# ¿Por qué funciona igual el programa sincronizando hilos que sin sincronizarlos?

Tags: python

estoy viendo el tema de los hilos en Python (Event, Lock, ...), pero haciendo pruebas, no me queda claro si estoy entendiendo bien el funcionamiento de los hilos en Python...

Yo tengo un pequeño programa muy simple, tengo una clase Counter con una propiedad valor inicializada a 0 y un método incrementa que cuando se le llama, aumenta el valor en 1. Por otro lado, tengo una clase Thread1 que hereda de threading.Thread, que recibe como argumento un objeto de tipo Counter y en el run llamo a incrementa (el método de counter)... Bien, en mi cabeza, la salida del programa no debería de ir ordenada, es decir, el valor no debería de ser 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... Debería ser aleatorio, ya que puede ser que dos hilos accedan a la vez al método incrementa y un valor se repita (por ejemplo, el hilo 1 y el hilo 2 acceden a la vez, y el valor que era 0, lo incrementan los dos a la vez, siendo 1 y mostrando 1 dos veces en pantalla)...

Y claro, al ver esto, me pregunto si estoy entendiendo bien los hilos...

Dejo aquí el programa sincronizado y sin sincronizar:

**sin_sincronizar.py:**

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-2s) %(message)s')

class Counter():
    def __init__(self, valor = 0):
        self.valor = valor

    def incrementa(self):
        self.valor += 1

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, args, name):
        super().__init__(args=args, name=name)
        self.counter = args[0]

    def run(self):
        self.counter.incrementa()
        logging.debug(self.counter.valor)

counter = Counter()

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread1(name='t{}'.format(i), args=(counter, ))
    t.start()
```

**sincronizado.py:**

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-2s) %(message)s')

class Counter():
    def __init__(self, valor = 0):
        self.valor = valor
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def incrementa(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            self.valor += 1
        finally:
            self.lock.release()

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, args, name):
        super().__init__(args=args, name=name)
        self.counter = args[0]

    def run(self):
        self.counter.incrementa()
        logging.debug(self.counter.valor)

counter = Counter()

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread1(name='t{}'.format(i), args=(counter, ))
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunas observaciones:

- No cabe esperar valores aleatorios en la salida. Cada vez que un hilo incrementa el contador, imprime por pantalla el valor incrementado. Ya que contador hay solo uno, los incrementos se producen secuencialmente (aunque sea por parte de diferentes hilos). El contador empieza valiendo 0, llega un hilo, lo incrementa y lo imprime, por tanto sale 1. Llega otro hilo (o tal vez el mismo), lo incrementa de nuevo y lo imprime, por tanto sale 2. Y así sucesivamente. El contador no toma valores aleatorios sino sucesivos.
- Sí que cabría esperar en cambio que a veces falte algún valor. Por ejemplo, el contador vale 3, llega un hilo, lo incrementa (4), y antes de que le dé tiempo a mostrarlo por pantalla, llega otro hilo y lo incrementa también (5), y luego un tercero lo incrementa y lo muestra, éste imprimriá 6. El 4 y 5 nunca serían mostrados. Es más, cuando se reanuden los hilos interrumpidos y muestren el contador, mostrarán 6 también. El 6 aparecerá 3 veces y el 4 y 5 ninguna. En cualquier caso los valores que se ven en pantalla son siempre crecientes.
- Estos casos son *altamente improbables*. El hilo tiene que ser interrumpido justo en el punto medio entre que acaba de incrementar el contador, y va a imprimirlo. Si no ocurre en ese momento, no notarás nada.
- Para remate, Python tiene una cosa llamada "GIL" (Global Interpreter Lock) que reduce todavía más las posibilidades de interferencia entre hilos. El GIL evita que dos hilos se estén ejecutando a la vez, en paralelo, incluso si tu máquina dispone de varias CPUs y cada hilo está en una CPU separada. El GIL fuerza a que se ejecuten por turnos. Una instrucción de un hilo (mientras los demás esperan), otra instrucción de otro hilo (mientras los restantes esperan), etc.

  <sup>Esto, dicho sea de paso, es una razón por la que no compensa usar threading en aplicaciones que requieran alto uso de CPU, siendo preferible el *multprocessin* para esos casos. No obstante, cuando usas bibliotecas externas escritas en C como numpy o pandas, éstas no están sujetas al GIL y sí que pueden ejecutar hilos en paralelo aprovechando los núcleos disponibles en tu máquina</sup>

Dicho todo lo anterior, la segunda implementación, con cerrojos, es la correcta. La primera contiene un potencial bug (que muestre valores repetidos y algunos ausentes). Ese bug es tan improbable que seguramente tendrías que ejecutar el programa cientos de veces y durante mucho tiempo para llegar a observarlo, pero sigue siendo un bug, que en la segunda implementación no está.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias abulafia, me ha quedado clarísimo!